# This is the error I got in Proteus (PC=0x00E8. [AVR AD CONVERTER] Reference value = 0. [U1])

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega32

[image: Proteus schematic with simulation log]

Got this error when I uploaded my elf file of the line following robot(virtual bot in proteus)
What does the error mean?

Answer (score 1):

i just had the same, i was using an arduino atmega 328p on proteus. just change AREF ( pin 17) to +1.75v or grater